# Android memory leak in a Thread run() function

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have this Thread which is running from a Service. The run's loop is running with no problem for around 15 minutes. After that - my GC gets crazy with a memory leak and then the function doesn't work good anymore.

I've used the DDMS Allocation Tracker to find the leak and it seems that the leak is inside the `input = in.readLine();` line. I don't really know how to solve it but this is my code, stack trace and Allocation Tracker snapshot:

**code**:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    startKeepAliveTimer();  
    try {
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
            if (socket != null)
            {
                Log.i("ServerConnection", "Server connection opened");
                this.app.setConnectedToServer(true);
                serverManager.loginToServer();
            }
            else
                app.setConnectedToServer(false);                
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String input;
            while (app.isConnectedToServer()) 
            {
                app.getFacebookManager().refreshAccessToken();                                      
                input = in.readLine();
                if (input != null)
                {
                    lastOnline = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    input = input.trim();
                    input = app.decrypt(input);
                    Log.e("Server Reponse", input);                 
                    serverManager.processData(app.convertToJSONObject(input));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ServerConnection", e.toString());
        }           

        Log.i("ServerConnection", "Server connection closed");
}



private void startKeepAliveTimer() {
    Timer timer = new Timer("keepAlive", true);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {         
        @Override
        public void run() {
            keepAlive();                
        }
    }, 0, keepAlive);
}
```

**stacktrace**

```
11-12 09:55:38.349: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1164K, 23% free 9987K/12871K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:38.899: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1072K, 23% free 9989K/12871K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:39.439: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1075K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 0ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:39.959: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 0ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:40.499: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9992K/12871K, paused 0ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:41.069: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1079K, 23% free 9983K/12871K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:41.749: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1094K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 2ms+2ms
11-12 09:55:42.379: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:42.909: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:43.459: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1061K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:43.979: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:44.549: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:45.079: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:45.629: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:46.179: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:46.709: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:47.229: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:47.749: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:48.299: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:48.839: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9989K/12871K, paused 1ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:49.379: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1075K, 23% free 9991K/12871K, paused 1ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:49.909: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1078K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:50.429: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 3ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:50.949: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:51.499: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:52.019: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 0ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:52.539: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:53.069: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 2ms+1ms
11-12 09:55:53.609: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 1ms+0ms
11-12 09:55:54.139: D/dalvikvm(2251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1045K, 23% free 9967K/12871K, paused 0ms+1ms
```

**Allocation Tracker:**
[image: DDMS Memory Allocation Tracker]

Comment: you never call close on the Socket instance. Maybe the issue is related

Comment: but i don't want to close it... its a persist connection to my server.. i close only when i have an error

Comment: Probably String is not efficient and get a lot of "dirty" memory in `input = input.trim();` and `input = app.decrypt(input);`. Try using `in.read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` and pre-allocate a char[], then decrypt the data in char[], it may help.

Comment: so why does the input = in.readLine() doesn't get collect when it ends (as u can see in the tracker)?

Comment: @AsafNevo it sounds like you are using a screwdriver for something you need to use a hammer for...

Comment: which means ? can you give me more details ?